# how to make caption be centered under table when using tex4ht?

Tags: tables, captions, tex4ht

What is the correct way to force tex4ht to put the caption under the table like it shows in pdf?

The caption always comes out shifted to the edge, while the table is centered OK in the middle of the web page.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|}\hline
A & B \\\hline
853.075 (sec) & 43.711 (sec)\\\hline
14.218 (minutes) & 0.729 (minutes)\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Total real time used to solve all problems}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Compiled with `lualatex foo.tex` the output is as expected:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compiled with `make4ht` using `make4ht -ulm default foo.tex "htm,mathjax"` or just `make4ht  foo.tex "htm"`  gives

[image]

Using TL 2018, updated 2 months ago, on Linux Ubuntu under windows 10 subsystem

Comment: Note: For KOMA-Script classes see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474282/9057

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can style the appearance of the generated document to your liking using CSS. The caption is contained in `<div class="caption">`, you can center it using the `text-align` property. Try the following configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{div.caption{text-align:center;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The result:

[image]