# longtable with caption has extra edge lines in tex4ht

Tags: captions, longtable, tex4ht

When I compile this MWE in `lualatex`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}    
This is my long table

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
\caption{my caption}\\\hline
A & B \\\hline
853.075 (sec) & 43.711 (sec)\\\hline
14.218 (minutes) & 0.729 (minutes)\\\hline
\end{longtable}

my long table is done    
\end{document}
```

The output comes as expected

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But using `make4ht  foo.tex -c my.cfg "htm"`   with `my.cfg` as

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{div.caption{text-align:center;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The HTML output looks like this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice the edge lines are too long.

If I remove the caption, then it is OK:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\usepackage{longtable}    
\begin{document}    
This is my long table

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}\hline 
A & B \\\hline
853.075 (sec) & 43.711 (sec)\\\hline
14.218 (minutes) & 0.729 (minutes)\\\hline
\end{longtable}

my long table is done    
\end{document}
```

And now compile using `make4ht foo.tex "htm"` then the output is OK, same as PDF

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If I use this .cfg file instead of the above

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{div.caption{text-align:center;}}
\Configure{float}{\csname par\endcsname\ShowPar}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="float">}}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}\ShowPar}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

On the first MWE shown above, then the output looks like this, where now the caption is inside the table itself

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which is not too bad, I can live with this. It looks better than the first example with the extra edges there.

Is there an easy workaround to the caption above the table without the extra lines? as in the PDF output?

Using TL 2018 on linux

references: [how-to-make-caption-be-centered-under-table-when-using-tex4ht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472625/how-to-make-caption-be-centered-under-table-when-using-tex4ht)

and

[how-to-have-a-caption-on-top-of-longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219138/how-to-have-a-caption-on-top-of-longtable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the caption is rendered as a row in a longtable. As you requested the borders for columns, you get a border also for the row with the caption. You can try the modified version of `longtable.4ht`, which prevents creation of the table row:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% longtable.4ht                         2009-05-21-09:32 %
% Copyright (C) 1997--2009       Eitan M. Gurari         %
%                                                        %
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the %
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either %
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any   %
% later version. The latest version of this license is   %
% in                                                     %
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt                %
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions %
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.                  %
%                                                        %
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".%
%                                                        %
% This Current Maintainer of this work                   %
% is Eitan M. Gurari.                                    %
%                                                        %
% If you modify this program your changing its signature %
% with a directive of the following form will be         %
% appreciated.                                           %
%            \message{signature}                         %
%                                                        %
%                             gurari@cse.ohio-state.edu  %
%                 http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\immediate\write-1{version 2009-05-21-09:32}

   \def\:tempc[#1]#2{%
  \gHAdvance\float:cnt  1
\gHAssign\capt:cnt0
\hbox{\def\flt:anchor{}\get:cptg}%
%
  \def\Clr{#2}\a:VBorder
\HAssign\ar:cnt0
\let\HAlign\empty
%
\def\aa:longtable{%
   \gdef\aa:longtable{\let\HRow\lt:sv
       \HAdvance\HRow by 1 \global\let\:MkHalign:\lt:MkHalign:}%
   \global\setbox\LT:box\vbox{\a:longtable}%
   \global\let\lt:MkHalign:\:MkHalign:}%
\def\bb:longtable{%
   \ifHCond \global\let\bb:longtable\empty
      \global\setbox\LT:ebox=\vbox{{\ht:everypar{}\leavevmode}\b:longtable}%
      \global\HCondfalse
   \fi}
%
  \refstepcounter{table}\stepcounter{LT@tables}%
  \if l#1%
    \LTleft\z@ \LTright\fill
  \else\if r#1%
    \LTleft\fill \LTright\z@
  \else\if c#1%
    \LTleft\fill \LTright\fill
  \fi\fi\fi
  \let\LT@mcol\multicolumn
  \let\LT@@tabarray\@tabarray
  \let\LT@@hl\hline
  \def\@tabarray{%
    \let\hline\LT@@hl
    \LT@@tabarray}%
  \let\\\LT@tabularcr\let\tabularnewline\\%
  \let\newpage\empty
\let\pagebreak\empty
\let\nopagebreak\empty
%
  \let\hline\LT@hline \let\kill\LT@kill\let\caption\LT@caption
  \@tempdima\ht\strutbox
  \let\@endpbox\LT@endpbox
  \ifx\extrarowheight\@undefined
    \let\@acol\@tabacol
    \let\@classz\@tabclassz \let\@classiv\@tabclassiv
    \def\@startpbox{\vtop\LT@startpbox}%
    \let\@@startpbox\@startpbox
    \let\@@endpbox\@endpbox
    \let\LT@LL@FM@cr\@tabularcr
  \else
    \advance\@tempdima\extrarowheight
    \col@sep\tabcolsep
    \let\@startpbox\LT@startpbox\let\LT@LL@FM@cr\@arraycr
  \fi
  \setbox\@arstrutbox\hbox{}%
  \let\@sharp##\let\protect\relax
   \begingroup
    \@mkpream{#2}%
    \xdef\LT@bchunk{%
       \global\advance\c@LT@chunks\@ne
       \global\LT@rows\z@\setbox\z@\vbox\bgroup
       \LT@setprevdepth
       \everycr{}\tabskip\LTleft\noexpand\MkHalign\noexpand\@sharp
   {\tabskip\z@ \@arstrut \@preamble \tabskip\LTright}%
}%
       \tmp:cnt=0
\global\let\:tempa\empty
\loop\ifnum \ar:cnt>\tmp:cnt
   \advance\tmp:cnt by 1
   \expandafter\ifx \csname @testpach \the\tmp:cnt\endcsname\relax
   \else
      \xdef\:tempa{%
          \:tempa
          \def \expandafter\noexpand
             \csname @testpach \the\tmp:cnt\endcsname{\csname @testpach
             \the\tmp:cnt\endcsname}}%
      \expandafter\let\csname @testpach \the\tmp:cnt\endcsname\relax
   \fi
\repeat
\aftergroup\:tempa
\xdef\:temp{%
   \def\noexpand\HAlign{\HAlign}%
   \def\noexpand\ar:cnt{\ar:cnt}}\aftergroup\:temp
%
  \endgroup
  \LT@cols\ar:cnt
%
  \LT@make@row
  \m@th\let\par\@empty
  \everycr{}\lineskip\z@\baselineskip\z@
  \ifx \EndPicture\:UnDef
     \SaveMkHalignConfig \ifx \recall:ar\:UnDef
   \edef\recall:ar{%
      \noexpand\ifx \noexpand\EndPicture\noexpand\:UnDef \noexpand\else
         \arrayrulewidth\the\arrayrulewidth
         \doublerulesep\the\doublerulesep
         \arraycolsep\the\arraycolsep
         \tabcolsep\the\tabcolsep
      \noexpand\fi }%
\fi
\arrayrulewidth\z@  \doublerulesep\z@
\arraycolsep\z@     \tabcolsep\z@
\Configure{MkHalign}
  \aa:longtable
  {\bb:longtable \ProperTrTrue}
  {\a:putHBorder\InitHBorder \ifProperTr{\c:longtable}}
  {\ifProperTr{\d:longtable}\a:putHBorder\InitHBorder}%
  {\ifProperTr{\e:longtable}\RecallMkHalignConfig\recall:ar}
  {\ifProperTr{\f:longtable}}
%
     \let\@sharp\relax
  \else \let\@sharp##\fi
  \LT@bchunk}
\HLet\LT@array\:tempc
\def\:tempc{%
  \crcr\LT@save@row\cr
  \ifx \EndPicture\:UnDef \EndMkHalign\else \egroup\fi
%
  \global\setbox\@ne\lastbox    \unskip
  \egroup}
\HLet\LT@echunk\:tempc
\let\:tempc\LT@startpbox
\append:defI\:tempc{\everypar{\HtmlPar}\a:longtableparbox}%
\HLet\LT@startpbox\:tempc
\NewConfigure{longtableparbox}{1}
\NewConfigure{longtable}{6}
\csname newbox\endcsname\LT:box
\csname newbox\endcsname\LT:ebox
\let\:tempc\LT@start
\pend:def\:tempc{%
  \ifvoid\LT@head\else
     \ifvoid\LT@firsthead
        \global\setbox\LT@firsthead=\hbox{\box\LT@head}%
     \else
        \global\setbox\tmp:bx=\hbox{\box\LT@head}%
  \fi\fi
  \box\LT:box}
\HLet\LT@start\:tempc
\let\:tempc\endlongtable
\append:def\:tempc{\box\LT:ebox}
\pend:def\:tempc{\global\HCondtrue}
\HLet\endlongtable\:tempc
\let\:tempc\LT@ntabularcr
\pend:def\:tempc{\global\let\lt:sv\HRow}
\HLet\LT@ntabularcr\:tempc
\let\:tempc\LT@end@hd@ft
\pend:defI\:tempc{\global\let\lt:sv\HRow}
\HLet\LT@end@hd@ft\:tempc
%\def\:tempc{\global\let\lt:sv\HRow}
%\HLet\LT@kill\:tempc
\def\LT@rebox#1\bgroup{%
  #1\bgroup
  \unskip
}
\let\:tempc\LT@kill
\pend:def\:tempc{\global\let\lt:sv\HRow}
\HLet\LT@kill\:tempc
\let\LT:argtabularcr\LT@argtabularcr
\def\:tempc{\global\let\lt:sv\HRow  \LT:argtabularcr}
\HLet\LT@argtabularcr\:tempc
\ifx \tmp:bx\:UnDef \csname newbox\endcsname \tmp:bx \fi
%\def\:tempc{\LT@end@hd@ft\tmp:bx}
%\HLet\endhead\:tempc
% \def\:tempc{\LT@end@hd@ft\tmp:bx}
% \HLet\endfoot\:tempc
\pend:def\LT@output{%
  \ifvoid\LT@foot\else
     \ifvoid\LT@lastfoot
        \global\setbox\LT@lastfoot=\hbox{\box\LT@foot}%
     \else
        \global\setbox\tmp:bx=\hbox{\box\LT@foot}%
  \fi\fi
}
\def\:tempc{\global\HCondtrue \LT@end@hd@ft\LT@lastfoot}
\HLet\endlastfoot\:tempc

   \def\:tempc{%
  \o:noalign:{\ifnum0=`}\fi
    \penalty\@M
    \futurelet\@let@token\LT@@hline}
\HLet\LT@hline\:tempc
\def\:tempc{%
  \ifx\@let@token\hline
    \global\let\@gtempa\@gobble
    \gdef\LT@sep{\penalty-\@medpenalty\vskip\doublerulesep}%
  \else
    \global\let\@gtempa\@empty
    \gdef\LT@sep{\penalty-\@lowpenalty\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}%
  \fi
  \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
  \a:hline
%
  \o:noalign:{\penalty\@M}%
  \@gtempa}
\HLet\LT@@hline\:tempc

   \def\:tempc{%
  \o:noalign:\bgroup \gHAdvance\TitleCount  1
    \bgroup\@ifnextchar[{\egroup\LT@c@ption\@firstofone}\LT@capti@n}
\HLet\LT@caption\:tempc
\NewConfigure{longtabcaption}{4}
\def\:tempc#1#2#3{%
\a:longtabcaption#1{\cap:ref{#2}}\b:longtabcaption#3\c:longtabcaption\egroup}
\Configure{longtabcaption}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\HCode{<caption id=""><strong>}}{\HCode{:</strong> }}{\HCode{</caption>}}

%  \LT@mcol\LT@cols c{\hbox{\parbox[t]\LTcapwidth{%
%       \cptA: #1{\cap:ref{#2}}\cptB:\cptC:#3\cptD:
%    \endgraf\vskip\baselineskip}}}}
\HLet\LT@makecaption\:tempc

\Hinput{longtable}
\endinput
```

It has it's issues, so I don't think we will use this in `tex4ht` by default, but it may work for you.

The result:

[image]

HTML code:

```xml
 <!--l. 8--><div class="longtable"> <table id="TBL-1" class="longtable" 
cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  
><colgroup id="TBL-1-1g"><col 
id="TBL-1-1" /></colgroup><colgroup id="TBL-1-2g"><col 
id="TBL-1-2" /></colgroup>
   <caption id=""><strong>Table 1:</strong> my caption</caption>
```