# tex4ht \Css code works using standard book class but has no effect using koma-script scrbook class

Tags: koma-script, tex4ht

I am using a `\Css` configuration  which centers a caption under a figure thanks to  [how-to-make-caption-be-centered-under-table-when-using-tex4ht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472625/how-to-make-caption-be-centered-under-table-when-using-tex4ht)

Now I find this does not work if I change document class to koma-script !

Here is a MWE

```
%\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{test image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Now compiled using `make4ht -c my.cfg` where `my.cfg` is

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{div.caption{text-align:center;}}
\Css{div.figure img {text-align:center;display:block;margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Gives the expected output

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now changed the document to

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
```

And making no other changes and compiling again using same command, gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Why would changing the document class makes the `CSS` configuration have no effect?

TL 2018

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you compare the generate HTML files, you will find, that tex4ht adds a table to the caption in case of `scrbook`:

```
<div class="caption">
  <table class="caption">
    <tr style="vertical-align:baseline;" class="caption">
      <td class="id">Figure&#x00A0;0.1: </td>
      <td class="content">test image</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

(I've changed the line breaks and the indent to make it human readable).

With this code not only the `text-align` but also the table alignment is responsible for the alignment. So you need one more line of css code:

```
div.caption table{margin: auto;}
```

This additionally changes the margin of the table. So with

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{div.caption{text-align:center;}}
\Css{div.figure img {text-align:center;display:block;margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;}}
\Css{div.caption table{margin: auto;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

You'd get what you want.

Comment: How do you know that? I don't even have any idea how to find out that!

Comment: @KeksDose As I wrote: 1st, I've compared the HTML files of using `book` and of using `scrbook`. Then, I've made the difference of the `scrbook` result better human readable. Then, I've had a look into the generated css file to see, whether or not there are already style definitions for `table` of class `caption` (in css syntax: `div.caption table`) or for table rows. Then, I've had a look into the css guide to see, how to reduce the table to its natural width or to change its alignment. That's it. No magic. Only reading code and manuals (and spending some time).